# How to make Aptitude clean up old kernels?

Tags: package-management, kernel, aptitude

On my laptop, I have several gigs of old kernels lying around, with package names such as linux-image-some_number-generic, linux-image-extra-some_number-generic, linux-headers-some_number, linux-headers-some_number-generic. I want to remove those old kernels, but in a 'safe' way, without inadvertently breaking my system. More specifically, I want to use the package manager [aptitude](https://wiki.debian.org/Aptitude).

I first discovered, from the question '[What does it mean that a package is "set to manually installed?"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/831/what-does-it-mean-that-a-package-is-set-to-manually-installed)', that aptitude would not remove these old kernels because they were installed 'manually'. This flag can easily be changed to an 'automatic' flag, which I did. But aptitude is not removing the old kernels regardless.

While trying to figure out why aptitude does not remove these packages, I came across the question '[Can I see why a package is installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5636/can-i-see-why-a-package-is-installed)'. Running the command

```
aptitude why linux-image-some_number-generic
```

gave me the output

```
i   nautilus                        Suggests totem | mp3-decoder
p   vlc-nox                         Provides mp3-decoder        
p   vlc-nox                         Depends  libcrystalhd3      
p   libcrystalhd3                   Suggests firmware-crystalhd 
p   firmware-crystalhd              Suggests linux-image        
i A linux-image-some_number-generic Provides linux-image
```

It seems that the packages linux-image-some_number-generic provide 'linux-image', which is suggested by a package I do not even have installed!

It seems that apt-get does not mind removing the old kernels (see also the comments to the accepted answer of the question '[Is aptitude still considered superior to apt-get?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1743/is-aptitude-still-considered-superior-to-apt-get/1749#1749)'). Running the command

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

produces the desired result; apt-get asks me if I want to remove all of the packages that I flagged 'automatic'.

My question is the following: How do I make aptitude remove these packages in a way such that aptitude ensures that no dependencies are broken?

EDIT: The following unanswered question seems to be related: [Aptitude conflicts with apt-get](https://askubuntu.com/questions/529197/aptitude-conflicts-with-apt-get).
EDIT: The following question may also be related: [aptitude ugrade does not change my kernel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/296196/aptitude-ugrade-does-not-change-my-kernel).
EDIT: I found a question on unix stackexchange which may also be related: [Aptitude doesn't remove automatically installed packages](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55425/aptitude-doesnt-remove-automatically-installed-packages).

Comment: Great question! aptitude does all my package management work except for this.